# hydrate in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

what is hydrate in nhibernate? I am not able to get my head around this term. 
This was used, in a video, in context of hydrating the child table rows.

Please advise.

Thanks
AJ

Comment: Can you provide a link to the video? I would assume we are talking about using a proxy when modelling 1-n or m-n relationships. This is called lazy loading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may wish to look at [Build Your own DAL](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/08/build-your-own-data-access-layer-series/). It has a section on hydration that you probably will find interesting.

But hydration from a really simple view means means take from the raw persistent storage module and map into an object/a list of objects.

**Update**

Look at [Understanding Lazy Loading Strategies](http://blogs.chayachronicles.com/sonofnun/archive/2007/03/30/230.aspx) or [Lazy Loading - Eager Loading](http://web.archive.org/web/20110514214657/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate.aspx). I think this is what is happening for the hydration of the objects in the video you describe.

**Example**

This is a really simple hydration example (Not an NHibernate example)

Say we have run a query like: select name, breed from tblDogs and that has these results

```
K9, GermanShepard
IBeBlind, Labrador
SmallAnoyance, Shitsu
Trigger, GermanShepard
```

And say we have the following object:

```
public class Dog {
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string breed { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can write our own hydrator:

```
public List<Dog> Hydrate(results rs) {
   List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
   foreach(Record rec in rs) {
     Dog d = new Dog();
     d.name = rec["name"];
     d.breed = rec["breed"];
     dogs.Add(d);
   }
  return dogs;
}
```

Comment: got it..thanks.. i have been hydrating data from database results all this time. Without knowing that it is hydrating of sorts.